# How not to interrupt the current process in the application when the user clicks on push?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-activity, push-notification

on one screen in my application, I am recording audio.

**Scenario:** User records audio on this screen. A push comes from our application. The user clicks on this push and another push processing activity is launched.

**Result:** The user loses his session.

**Question:** what are the options for handling this case so that the user does not lose his session? Ideally, before switching to a new activity, the application would ask the user if he is sure that he wants to go to another screen, because the session will be lost. But how to track it?

Thanks a lot for your advice

Comment: Option 1: The recording should be moved to a service when the activity is not visible. The recording will continue in the background with a push notification indicating that it is still running. Option 2: Push notification and recording activity should be the same activity with different fragments. When the push starts the activity, the recording activity is reopened and it can check if it should open a fragment for the push message or ask the user to save their session.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann 
Option 1.
Registration is already taking place in the service. But as soon as the user clicks push in the notification shade, the app restarts, as only one app process is allowed at a time.
Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I have found is to clear all old push notifications in the notification shade when going to the recording screen.

```
val notificationsManager = getSystemService<Any>(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager?
notificationsManager!!.cancelAll()
```

Further during the recording, if a push notification arrives, I receive this in my service inherited from FirebaseMessagingService in onMessageReceived().

If the recording screen is currently open, I do not show a notification in the notification shade. But I show a widget on the recording screen with the push text and if the user presses it I ask if the user wants to go to another screen because the recording will end.

I hope my experience helps someone. Similarly implemented in Intercom